# Can anyone identify this biplane from 1920s-1930s?

Tags: aircraft-identification, biplane

It was my grandfather's, but he is no longer around to ask. He lived in Nebraska.
[image]

Comment: The car behind looks like a Packard 12 coupe quite an upmarket vehicle especially given the economic climate of the early 30s 
https://classiccars.com/listings/view/1275436/1934-packard-twelve-for-sale-in-morgantown-pennsylvania-19543

Answer (score 9):

It looks like a 1928 [Swallow TP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swallow_TP) by Swallow Airplane Company.

[image: Swallow TP]
([source](https://aircraft-in-focus.com/wp-content/gallery/swallow-n8761/img_4827-800x.jpg))
(Swallow TP at [Yanks Air Museum](https://yanksair.org/) in Chino California.  Photo plus some information about the specific aircraft may also be seen on [this website](http://aircraft-in-focus.com/laird-swallow/) )

[image: s tp]
([source](https://c8.alamy.com/comp/E3TDF5/swallow-tp-E3TDF5.jpg))

Comment: I added some information about the top photo, feel free to roll back or modify if for some reason you don't think it helps the anwer.

Comment: Yes, that looks like it. Thank you so much!